# syntax error in bulk API

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any parameter to let elasticsearch know that it is OK to proceed with the next record even if it encounters an error? For e.g. this works correctly.

```
DELETE /test

PUT /test

PUT /_bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" }}
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }

get /test/type1/_search
```

In case of syntax error, I will prefer to skip that row and load the next one. In the following case, I would insert ID 3 even if ID 1 failed due to extra { on line 2

```
PUT /_bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" }}
{ "field1" : "value1" } {
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
```

Comment: Is bulk stopping on any error? as according to my knowledge it won't step or throw any error if any single request fails.

Comment: If you run the above code you will see that due to unclosed { both the records failed. While I expected the second record to pass.

Comment: If you are leaving a unclosed bracket then the bulk api won't understand when that document is ending. Bulk has error handling for internal errors not errors passed in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch bulk updates don’t stop on *operational* errors, but the issue you are experiencing is due to a *programmer* error. Problem is, if there’s a syntax error in your request then there’s no way for Elasticsearch to be able to parse your request. From the documentation on bulk updates – [Why the funny format?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/distrib-multi-doc.html#bulk-format):

> Elasticsearch reaches up into the networking buffer, where the raw request has been received, and reads the data directly. It uses the newline characters to identify and parse just the small action/metadata lines in order to decide which shard should handle each request.
>
> These raw requests are forwarded directly to the correct shard. There is no redundant copying of data, no wasted data structures. The entire request process is handled in the smallest amount of memory possible.

If there is a syntax error somewhere, it won’t be able to identify action / request lines.

Comment: I expect it to pass the programmer error just like it passes operational errors. I am trying to import vast amount of logs data. The aim is to import as much data as possible and data integrity does not matter in my case.